# Post increment an integer in PowerShell initialised to a negative value

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the following code which initialises a value to -1:

```
Set-Variable -Name ID -Value -1 -Scope local
```

When I do it like this,

```
$local:ID++
```

I get the following error:

> The '++' operator works only on numbers. The operand is a
>   'System.String'.

I thought it will implicitly consider this as int. But, I have to use a workaround which is not neat:

**Workaround:**

```
$intVal = [int]$local:ID
$intval ++
```

Is there another approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$id is a string (type $id.gettype() to find its type). In order to initialize it as an integer, put it in parenthesis:

```
PS> Set-Variable -Name ID -Value (-1) -Scope local
PS> ($local:ID++) #increment and print the variable 
0
```

Comment: Cool. How are we suppose to know such stuffs that we should put brackets around a variable to enforce the data type. Its weird !

Comment: Bow you know :), if the value doesn't start with a number it is considered as a string, in your case the value starts with a hyphen. Enclosing it in parenthesis forces the expression.

Comment: Thanks Shay, that explains :) Can you pls point to some resource regarding this paranthesis usage in powershell where I can read up ?

Comment: Check out the PowerShell 2.0 Language Specification
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2011/04/16/powershell-language-now-licensed-under-the-community-promise.aspx